# Selenium script executes differently based on whether or not default Firefox profile is used

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

In the following two blocks of code, the last line seems to execute differently and I'm not sure why:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('Path to firefox profile')
profile.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)
profile.update_preferences()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
driver.get("https://google.com/")
time.sleep(6)
driver.execute_script("window.open('');")

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://google.com/")
time.sleep(6)
driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
```

In the first snippet, `driver.execute_script` opens up a new window, but in the second snippet,`driver.execute_script` opens up a new tab. Why do the two snippets have different behavior for `driver.execute_script` ?

My guess is that in the first snippet there is some profile preference that is causing it to create new windows instead of tabs but I'm not sure what profile setting to change to make the behavior match exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Your second instance of browser is being opened because of `driver = webdriver.Firefox()`. `driver.execute_script("window.open('');")` will open new tab only.